# Why is CMAKE_C_COMPILER_VERSION reporting the wrong version? clang 13 unused-but-set-variable/unused-but-set-parameter check

Tags: c++, c, cmake, clang

On a CI machine I have cmake echoing back some basic compiler variables at the start. After updating clang from 12 to 13, I am seeing both versions here:

```
-- CMAKE_C_COMPILER: /usr/local/bin/clang
-- CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID: Clang
-- CMAKE_C_COMPILER_VERSION: 12.0.0
clang version 13.0.0 (/tmp/llvm-project/clang d7b669b3a30345cfcdb2fde2af6f48aa4b94845d)
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER: /usr/local/bin/clang++
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID: Clang
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION: 12.0.0
clang version 13.0.0 (/tmp/llvm-project/clang d7b669b3a30345cfcdb2fde2af6f48aa4b94845d)
```

Note that "13.0.0" comes from actually running `clang --version` via these cmake functions:

```
message(STATUS "CMAKE_C_COMPILER: " ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} )
message(STATUS "CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID: ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID}")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_C_COMPILER_VERSION: ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_VERSION}")
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} ${COMPILER_VERSION_ARG} )
```

Additional info that might be relevant:

```
-- CMake version: 3.18.1-g262b901
-- Using ccache.
-- Using sanitizer: address
```

The issue becomes relevant because some later build steps fail as they are checking the compiler version and thus making the wrong decisions. Is there some local caching that could result in such weird behavior? To my understanding this should not be dependent on caching though?

**Update:** I tossed the CMAKE_C_COMPILER_VERSION check and used check_c_compiler_flag instead, see my answer below.

Comment: "After updating clang from 12 to 13" - Have you clear CMake cache after updating clang?E.g. by removing project's build directory. "13.0.0 comes from actually running `clang --version`" - Since CMake finds `/usr/local/bin/clang`, I would better run `/usr/local/bin/clang -- version` for check.

Comment: I clarified the part about `clang --version` and why it's the same executable. Are you saying CMake is allowed to cache the compiler version and does not notice when it gets a major update? That'd rather be quite bananas, no?

Answer (score 1):

Clang 13 introduced two new checks that broke some external libs. Instead of checking the clang version doing a feature check is better anyway:

```
# clang 13 introduced stricter checks, for now, disable the warning:
include(CheckCCompilerFlag)
check_c_compiler_flag(-Wno-unused-but-set-variable HAS_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE)
if (HAS_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-unused-but-set-variable")
endif()
```

The same can be applied to `-Wno-unused-but-set-parameter`, of course. Also use `CheckCxxCompilerFlag`/`check_cxx_compiler_flag` instead for C++.

Comment: In a word: elegant

Answer (score 0):

CMake found `/usr/local/bin/clang`, not `/tmp/llvm-project/clang`. You might want to explicitly set CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to ensure that CMake finds the Clang you intend it should be used.

Comment: /tmp/llvm-project/clang is part of the version string when you run `clang --version`, so no, that's not it.

Comment: Have you checked CMakeCache for the actual path that is used? And did it help to force the compiler by setting the variables?

Comment: It's a CI box, where such things are limited. Also, I cannot access old logs anymore, so cannot investigate further.